# How to programatically add a product tag to a specific product?

Tags: development

I would I am creating an import script. I would like to know how to programatically add a product tag via php script?

Any experience doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To programatically add tag to a product, try the below solution :

```
  $productIds = array(
        $product_id_1,
        $product_id_2
    );

$tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')
    ->load('my_tag_name', 'name');

Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation')
    ->addRelations($tag, $productIds);
```

Comment: this gives me an error of a:5:{i:0;s:214:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'store_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `vwkvtag_relation` (`tag_id`,`store_id`,`product_id`,`customer_id`,`created_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:2375:"#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Answer (score 0):

**You can add a tag  by below code:**

```
$tagName=preg_replace("/(\'(.*?)\')|(\s+)/i", "$1\n", $tagNamesInString)
 $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');

    // added tag relation statuses
    $counter = array(
        Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::ADD_STATUS_NEW => array(),
        Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::ADD_STATUS_EXIST => array(),
        Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::ADD_STATUS_SUCCESS => array(),
        Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::ADD_STATUS_REJECTED => array()
    );


 $tagModel->unsetData()->loadByName($tagName);

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
if (!$tagModel->getId()) {
            $tagModel->setName($tagName)
                ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
                ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                ->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())
                ->save();
   }

$relationStatus = $tagModel->saveRelation($productId, $customerId, $storeId);
```

Comment: And how about without customer?